# Case sensitive column name in insert query for databasechangelog generated by liquibase maven plugin for postgres

Tags: postgresql, maven, liquibase

I tried to use liquibase-maven-plugin to update my postgres database.

Following is the plugin config in my pom file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Liquibase properties file is as follows.

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myserver
username=postgres
password=password
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
verbose=true
dropFirst=false
```

Then I executed the following command to update a blank database.

```
mvn liquibase:update
```

But I see the following error.

[image]

To understand the problem, I generated the SQL that was being executed using following command.

```
mvn liquibase:updateSQL
```

The above command generated following SQL.

```
-- Create Database Lock Table
CREATE TABLE databasechangeloglock (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (ID));

-- Initialize Database Lock Table
DELETE FROM databasechangeloglock;

INSERT INTO databasechangeloglock (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, FALSE);

-- Lock Database
UPDATE databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = 'DESKTOP-9U9TDA6 (192.168.0.110)', LOCKGRANTED = '2018-07-20 16:32:11.048' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE;

-- Create Database Change Log Table
CREATE TABLE databasechangelog (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INTEGER NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10));

-- Changeset src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::1482291859539-1::aguna (generated)
CREATE TABLE "Environment" ("Id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "Name" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "Notes" VARCHAR(255), "SitePassword" VARCHAR(255), "SiteSecret" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "SiteUser" VARCHAR(255), "Status" BOOLEAN NOT NULL, "Url" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "CONSTRAINT_E" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"));

INSERT INTO "databasechangelog" ("ID", "AUTHOR", "FILENAME", "DATEEXECUTED", "ORDEREXECUTED", "MD5SUM", "DESCRIPTION", "COMMENTS", "EXECTYPE", "CONTEXTS", "LABELS", "LIQUIBASE", "DEPLOYMENT_ID") VALUES ('1482291859539-1', 'aguna (generated)', 'src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml', NOW(), 1, '8:1be0ac538f0540ba1bf94f6f2ac8d466', 'createTable tableName=Environment', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.6.2', '2084531992');

-- Release Database Lock
UPDATE databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1;
```

I observed, script to create table databasechangelog **do not** have column names double quoted i.e. column names are created in lower case(default case for postgres). But script to insert record in the same table has column names in caps and double quoted i.e. case is maintained. Since postgres is case sensitive hence the insert statement throws the mentioned exception.

To me it appears to be problem with the plugin. Any solution here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found answer to the problem. I had defined following in root of "databaseChangeLog" in master changelog file i.e. db.changelog-master.yaml. I removed it from there and added it to child changelog files and changesets wherever required.

```
- objectQuotingStrategy: QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS
```

It works fine now. I also saw following ticket open that speaks about a related bug in liquibase. It could be because of that.

https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3073